# CouchDB historical view snapshots

Tags: couchdb

I have a database with documents that are roughly of the form:

```
{"created_at": some_datetime, "deleted_at": another_datetime, "foo": "bar"}
```

It is trivial to get a count of non-deleted documents in the DB, assuming that we don't need to handle "deleted_at" in the future.  It's also trivial to create a view that reduces to something like the following (using UTC):

```
[
  {"key": ["created", 2012, 7, 30], "value": 39},
  {"key": ["deleted", 2012, 7, 31], "value": 12}
  {"key": ["created", 2012, 8, 2], "value": 6}
]
```

...which means that 39 documents were marked as created on 2012-07-30, 12 were marked as deleted on 2012-07-31, and so on.  What I want is an efficient mechanism for getting the snapshot of how many documents "existed" on 2012-08-01 (0+39-12 == 27).  Ideally, I'd like to be able to query a view or a DB (e.g. something that's been precomputed and saved to disk) with the date as the key or index, and get the count as the value or document.  e.g.:

```
[
  {"key": [2012, 7, 30], "value": 39},
  {"key": [2012, 7, 31], "value": 27},
  {"key": [2012, 8,  1], "value": 27},
  {"key": [2012, 8,  2], "value": 33}
]
```

This can be computed easily enough by iterating through all of the rows in the view,  keeping a running counter and summing up each day as I go, but that approach slows down as the data set grows larger, unless I'm smart about caching or storing the results.  Is there a smarter way to tackle this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an approach that seems much better than my original one, assuming that you only care about a single date:

```
def size_at(date=Time.now.to_date)
  ymd = [date.year, date.month, date.day]
  added = view.reduce.
    startkey(["created_at"]).
    endkey(  ["created_at", *ymd, {}]).rows.first || {}
  deleted = view.reduce.
    startkey(["deleted_at"]).
    endkey(  ["deleted_at", *ymd, {}]).rows.first || {}
  added.fetch("value", 0) - deleted.fetch("value", 0)
end
```

Basically, let CouchDB do the reduction for you.  I didn't originally realize that you could mix and match reduce with startkey/endkey.

Unfortunately, this approach requires two hits to the DB (although those could be parallelized or pipelined).  And it doesn't work as well when you want to get a lot of these sizes at once (e.g. view the whole history, rather than just look at one date).

Answer (score 0):

Just for the sake of comparison (I'm hoping someone has a better solution), here's (more or less) how I'm currently solving it (in untested ruby pseudocode):

```
require 'date'

def date_snapshots(rows)
  current_date  = nil
  current_count = 0
  rows.inject({}) {|hash, reduced_row|
    type, *ymd = reduced_row["key"]
    this_date  = Date.new(*ymd)
    if current_date
      # deal with the days where nothing changed
      (current_date.succ ... this_date).each do |date|
        key       = date.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
        hash[key] = current_count
      end
    end
    # update the counter and deal with the current day
    current_date   = this_date
    current_count += reduced_row["value"] if type == "created_at"
    current_count -= reduced_row["value"] if type == "deleted_at"
    key       = current_date.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
    hash[key] = current_count
    hash
  }
end
```

Which can then be used like so:

```
rows = couch_server.db(foo).design(bar).view(baz).reduce.group_level(3).rows
date_snapshots(rows)["2012-08-01"]
```

Obvious small improvement would be to add a caching layer, although it isn't quite as trivial to make that caching layer play nicely incremental updates (e.g. the changes feed).